# Returning Error at Java Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, error-handling

I have a class like that:

```
@Override
public StudentDTO getStudent(@WebParam(name = "name") String studentName) {
    StudentDTO student = new StudentDTO();
    try {
        student = studentService.findStudentByName(studentName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ErrorActionResponse("student couldn't find by name");
    }
    return student;
}
```

As usual this doesn't work because of return type is *StudentDTO* and I try to return another type of class: *ErrorActionResponse*. ErrorActionResponse is an error class that has detailed information about error.

How can I design my web service architecture that can handle error situations? (At my REST architecture I write error information into response and send error to client side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a `Collection` (as stated in a comment to my earlier answer), I suggest you create a Map with two keys. If there is no exception, first key-value pair will contain "students" string and `StudentDTO` collection, respectively. And, second key-value pair will contain "exception" string and null value, respectively. If there is an exception, first key-value pair will contain "students" string and null value, respectively. And, second key-value pair will be "exception" string and an `ErrorActionResponse` object, respectively. Example:

No exception case:

```
Map<String, List> result = new HashMap<String, List>();
result.put( "students", COLLECTION_OF_STUDENTS );
result.put( "exception", null );
```

No exception case:

```
Map<String, List> result = new HashMap<String, List>();
result.put( "students", null );
result.put( "exception", ErrorActionResponse_OBJECT );
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

For least impact I suggest:
Make `ErrorActionResponse` as a private member of `StudentDTO` with setter and getter methods. In service, when there's an exception, instantiate `ErrorActionResponse` and set same in `StudentDTO`'s member. So, client has to first check if `getErrorActionResponse()` returns `null`. If so, do normal processing else, handle exception case.

CLASS StudentDTO:

```
public class StudentDTO {

    ...
    private ErrorActionResponse errorActionResponse;
    ...

    public ErrorActionResponse getErrorActionResponse() {
        return errorActionResponse;
    }

    public void setErrorActionResponse( ErrorActionResponse errorActionResponse ) {
        this.errorActionResponse = errorActionResponse;
    }

}
```

SERVICE:

```
@Override
public StudentDTO getStudent(@WebParam(name = "name") String studentName) {
    StudentDTO student = new StudentDTO();
    try {
        student = studentService.findStudentByName(studentName);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        student.setErrorActionResponse( new ErrorActionResponse("student couldn't find by name") );
    }
    finally {
        return student;
    }
}
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
if( student.getErrorActionResponse() == null ) {
    // do normal processing
}
else {
    // handle exception case
}
```

In the above case, DTO has `ErrorActionResponse` member which is not related to it's fundamental state. So, for cleaner approach, I suggest you to consider [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Comment: If I try to return list of students I will need to set all student's errorActionResponse at the list

Comment: I agree. My first suggestion was for your OP requirement - method that returns a student and not a list (which you are stating now).